# RailsLayout gem doesn't create expected files

Tags: learn-ruby-on-rails

Following the example in the book [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html), I ran `rails generate layout:install foundation5 --force`
and then checked for the *framework_and_overrides.css.scss* file in the *app/assets/stylesheets/* folder.  It did not remove the *simple.css* file and I suspect did not modify the other files mentioned.  This is setting up the Zurb Foundation layout stuff.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I investigated and built the app following the instructions in the book and was unable to duplicate the problem. No one else has reported the problem. Have you found out anything more?

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the followup.  I ran the line again this morning - suddenly things seem to be in place now.  Only thing I can think that may have prevented before was a storage issue on nitrous - but regardless, I will proceed now.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am having the same problem. When I run `rails generate layout:install foundation5`, it does not display any output.